# myList.First() vs myList[0] - Which is better?

Tags: c#, list

When accessing the first element in a list is it better to use myList.First() or access the members directly via their index (i.e myList[0])?

In terms of how long it takes to complete the operation using the direct index works much faster:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var listOfInts = new List<int>
    {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    };
    int? first;

    var sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    first = listOfInts.First();
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("First Element(.First()): [" + first + "] Took: " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");

    sw.Reset();
    first = null;

    sw.Start();
    first = listOfInts[0];
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("First Element(idx[0]): [" + first + "] Took: " + sw.ElapsedTicks + " ticks");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When using `.First()` it takes between 3000-5000 ticks compared to `idx[0]` taking 1-2 ticks. Is there a standard or reason for using `.First()`? Most of the examples I have found online use `.First()` however, if you know that the list has elements in it then why not directly access it via its index?

Comment: ``.First()`` since it works for all ``IEnumerable``. ``[0]`` only works for indexed collections.

Comment: That's a very bad performance test. Not only is there no warm up - but you're only testing each case once.

Comment: I was just trying to give an idea of the test scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your performance test is terrible.

The actual performance factor is about 1.9x slower for `.First()` than `[0]`.

Here's how to test properly:

```
Func<Action, int, TimeSpan> measure = (a, c) =>
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (var i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        a();
    };
    sw.Stop();
    return sw.Elapsed;
};

var listOfInts = new List<int>
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};
int? value;

Action indexed = () =>
{
    value = listOfInts[0];
};

Action first = () =>
{
    value = listOfInts.First();
};  

// warm up runs
measure(indexed, 1);
measure(first, 1);

var measurements =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10) // run 10 separate tests
        .Select(x => new
        {
            indexed = measure(indexed, 1000000), // 1M iterations
            first = measure(first, 1000000), // 1M iterations
        })
        .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(measurements.Select(x => x.indexed.TotalMilliseconds).Average());
Console.WriteLine(measurements.Select(x => x.first.TotalMilliseconds).Average());
```

That gives results like:

```
10.1342
19.52894
```

Meaning that you can do 1,000,000 `[0]` in 10.1342ms & 1,000,000 `.First()` in 19.52894ms.

In practical terms, it's hardly any difference really.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `First`. Why? A couple of reasons:

1. Generalization, `First` works on any `IEnumerable`. Generalization, even if premature, when extremely cheap, is normally a good idea.
2. More readable; code is easier to read and understand.
3. Performance impact is negligable.

   Contrary to what some believe, `First` does not create an iterator block and then returns the first element. What it does is it checks if the enumeration implements `IList` and if it does, it returns the first element directly. Something along the lines of:

   ```
   var list = source as IList<TSource>;

   if (list != null)
   {
       if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
   }
   else 
   {
       //iterator block
   }

   //throw empty enumeration
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`First()` also works with other collection types.

If your interface only defines an `ICollection<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, you can not use the index because it is not defined by these interfaces. To get an element at an arbitrary position, you can use `ElementAt(indexPosition)`.

If you are sure you got a `T[]` or an `IList<T>`, use the index.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of `First` is that you can use a `lambda` expression to describe a condition and get the first element, that meets that condition:

```
List<int> a = new List<int>();
int r = a.First(i => i > 5);
```

If you just want the first item of the collection there is ne real difference.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your requirements and - to a certain extend - on your personal preferences.

- **`myList[0]`**: A list allows random access and so there is nothing wrong with using it. When you know it's a list or an array and you are posive that the first element exists (or you're OK with an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`), you can access the element like that. Also, any reader of your code will understand what you're doing.
- **`myList.First()`**: With `First()` you access the first element via LINQ, which works on any `IEnumerable<T>`, which gives you more flexibility. LINQ also provides additional extension methods that go further than just accessing the element, namely `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()` and `SingleOrDefault()`, which allows you to tailor access to the situation. On the downside, LINQ has some performance impact, which in most of the cases in practice should be irrelevant. However, if you are in one of the rare cases where performance *does* matter, be careful with LINQ.

So in short: If you want simplicity and performance, use `myList[0]`. If you want flexibility, use LINQ. The differences are small though, so if you like one of the ways better than the other, just use it. In any case, the result will be exactly the same (the only difference being that `myList[0]` throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, while `First()` throws an `InvalidOperationException`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. First function is using indexer anyway.

But if there is no element on the list First() function will throw a 'System.InvalidOperationException'. But indexer will throw 'System.OutOfRangeException'

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```